# How do I call get twice in a row in Python?

Tags: python-2.x

I'm trying to get a Python script to append two different prefixes to a command that come from two different environment variables. Currently the script is only configured to accept different prefixes from ONE variable, and is stubbornly resisting my attempts to make it take two variables.

The code looks like this:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen([subst.get('TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX','') + 'readelf', '-d', lib], stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
```

If I just replace TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX with GNU_PREFIX, which is the other environment variable I want, the code works as-is. But if I try to do something like...

```
proc = subprocess.Popen([subst.get('TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX','') + subst.get('GNU_PREFIX','') + 'readelf', '-d', lib], stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
```

It doesn't work. In fact, Python seems to be stubbornly not allowing me to call "get" twice, or to combine the two flags.

What I want is to make it take both these variables as input and tack them onto the front of the command in order. Fixing the Makefiles was easy, but this Python script is like Greek to me. So for instance, I want something where this..

- TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX = "s"
- GNU_PREFIX = "g"

Can produce a command like this:

sgreadelf -d

And if either one isn't set, it's just omitted.

- TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX = "s"
- GNU_PREFIX = ""

Should produce:

sreadelf -d

- TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX = ""
- GNU_PREFIX = "g"

greadelf -d

It's very frustrating and the code seems to be very stubborn about only letting me pull in one environment variable. If I add the other variable as an argument, it says too many arguments. If I add it as a second command, it doesn't like that either.

Is there really just no way to pull in two environment variables and append both of them to the beginning of a string? It seems like it should be simple, but they seem bent on not letting me do it easily without reading an entire book on Python.

EDIT: Sorry, I forgot to mention where "subst" comes from. I thought it was a builtin command, but apparently it's defined elsewhere. I know next to nothing about Python.

```
config = buildObject.from_environment()

for var in ('topsrcdir', 'topobjdir', 'defines', 'non_global_defines',
            'substs'):
    value = getattr(config, var)
    setattr(sys.modules[__name__], var, value)

substs = dict(substs)

for var in os.environ:
    if var not in ('CPP', 'CXXCPP', 'SHELL') and var in substs:
        substs[var] = os.environ[var]
```

And here is the error:

```
File "/export/home/jeremy/Downloads/git/Solaris-UXP/toolkit/library/dependentlibs.py", line 55
      proc = subprocess.Popen([substs.get(('TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX', '') + ('GNU_PREFIX', '') + 'readelf', '-d', lib], stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
                                                                                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This time I tried it without subst.get, but it gives the exact same error whether I put subst.get in front of the second argument or not. It's like it just won't let me put anything else on that command line.

EDIT2: I've been messing with the code and trying various things to get it to work, sorry it wasn't the exact same error I reported the first time. Here's two other things I tried and the error output messages.

```
   File "/export/home/jeremy/Downloads/git/Solaris-UXP/toolkit/library/dependentlibs.py", line 55, in dependentlibs_readelf
 proc = subprocess.Popen([substs.get(('TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX', '') + ('GNU_PREFIX', '')) + 'readelf', '-d', lib], stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
 TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'

 File "/export/home/jeremy/Downloads/git/Solaris-UXP/toolkit/library/dependentlibs.py", line 55, in dependentlibs_readelf
  proc = subprocess.Popen([substs.get('TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX', '') + substs.get('GNU_PREFIX', '') + 'readelf', '-d', lib], stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 394, in __init__
  errread, errwrite)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1047, in _execute_child
  raise child_exception
  OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

EDIT3: I can't fit the entire output of printing 'substs' here, and it reveals more about what I'm working on than I really wanted to share originally, but basically it's about 60,000 characters of this:

```
{'MOZ_PERMISSIONS': '1', 'ANDROID_ANIMATED_VECTOR_DRAWABLE_AAR_LIB': '', 'X_LIBS': ' -L/usr/lib -R/usr/lib', 'CAIRO_FT_CFLAGS': ['-I/usr/include/freetype2', '-I/usr/include/libpng16', '-I/usr/include/harfbuzz', '-I/usr/include/glib-2.0', '-I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include', '-I/usr/include/pcre', '-I/usr/include/freetype2', '-I/usr/include/libpng16', '-I/usr/include/harfbuzz', '-I/usr/include/glib-2.0', '-I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include', '-I/usr/include/pcre'], 'MOZ_WIDGET_TOOLKIT': 'gtk2', 'MOZ_JPEG_LIBS': [], 'MOZ_ANDROID_MIN_SDK_VERSION': '', 'prefix': '/usr/local', 'TK_CFLAGS': ['-I/export/home/athenian/Downloads/git/Solaris-UXP/widget/gtk/compat', '-D_REENTRANT', '-D_PTHREADS', '-D_REENTRANT', '-D_POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS', '-I/usr/include/gtk-2.0', '-I/usr/include/gtk-unix-print-2.0', '-I/usr/include/gtk-2.0', '-I/usr/include/atk-1.0', '-I/usr/include/gtk-2.0', '-I/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/include', '-I/usr/include/pango-1.0', '-I/usr/include/fribidi', '-I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/', '-I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0', '-I/usr/include/libpng16', '-I/usr/include/cairo', '-I/usr/include/pixman-1', '-I/usr/include/freetype2', '-I/usr/include/harfbuzz', '-I/usr/include/glib-2.0', '-I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include', '-I/usr/include/pcre', '-I/usr/include/drm', '-I/usr/include/libpng16'], 'CPP': ['/usr/bin/gcc', '-E', '-std=gnu99'], 'MOZ_ALLOW_HEAP_EXECUTE_FLAGS': [], 'SSSE3_FLAGS': ['-mssse3'], 'MOZ_APP_BASENAME': 'Palemoon', 'AR_EXTRACT': '$(AR) x', 'mandir': '${prefix}/man', 'MOZ_APP_ANDROID_VERSION_CODE': '', 'ANDROID_PLAY_SERVICES_ADS_AAR': '', 'MOZILLA_VERSION': '4.4.0', 'TAR': '/usr/bin/gtar', 'MOZ_SYSTEM_JPEG': '', 'build_alias': 'i386-pc-solaris2.11', 'XLDFLAGS': ['-L/usr/lib', '-R/usr/lib'], 'STRIP': 'strip', 'MOZ_VPX_ERROR_CONCEALMENT': '', 'ZLIB_IN_MOZGLUE': '', 'CAIRO_TEE_CFLAGS': [], 'localstatedir': '${prefix}/var', 'ANDROID_SDK_ROOT': '', 'ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_AAR': '', 'CLANG_CL': '', 'NONASCII': '', 'BUILD_ARM_NEON': '', 'build_vendor': 'pc', 'MOZ_FFVPX': '', 'VPX_ASFLAGS': ['-DPIC'], 'MOZ_APP_ID': '{8de7fcbb-c55c-4fbe-bfc5-fc555c87dbc4}', 'ANDROID_DESIGN_AAR': '', 'AAPT': '', 'MOZ_PNG_CFLAGS': [], 'MOZ_CAIRO_OSLIBS': ['-L/usr/lib', '-R/usr/lib', '-lXrender'], 'HAVE_TOOLCHAIN_SUPPORT_MSSE4_1': '1', 'AUTOCONF': '/usr/bin/autoconf-2.13', 'CLANG_LDFLAGS': '', 'RELEASE_OR_BETA': '1', 'WIN_UCRT_REDIST_DIR': '', 'HOST_LDFLAGS': '', 'VISIBILITY_FLAGS': ['-I/export/home/athenian/Downloads/git/Solaris-UXP/obj-release/dist/system_wrappers', '-include', '/export/home/athenian/Downloads/git/Solaris-UXP/config/gcc_hidden.h'], 'MOZILLA_UAVERSION': '4.4', 'MOZ_ASAN': '', 'MOZ_APP_UA_NAME': '', 'MOZ_STARTUP_NOTIFICATION_LIBS': [], 'LIBOBJS': '', 'MOZ_ENABLE_DWRITE_FONT': '', 'MOZ_GNOMEUI_LIBS': [], 'MOZ_COMPONENTS_VERSION_SCRIPT_LDFLAGS': '', 'MKSHLIB': '$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(DSO_PIC_CFLAGS) $(DSO_LDOPTS) -Wl,-h,$(DSO_SONAME) -o $@', 'MOZ_JPEG_CFLAGS': [], 'JS_POSIX_NSPR': '', 'host_cpu': 'i386', 'XCFLAGS': [], 'NSS_EXTRA_SYMBOLS_FILE': '', 'ICU_DATA_FILE': 'icudt58l.dat', 'DSO_LDOPTS': '-shared', 'ANDROID_PLAY_SERVICES_MEASUREMENT_AAR': '', 'PROFILE_USE_CFLAGS': '-fprofile-use
```

The rest is here, if you need it:

https://pastebin.com/cQr0AUTW

Comment: Where does `subst` come from? What error does it give you. Please try to give more details that can help us in helping you.

Comment: Well, the fact that subst had to come from somewhere was news to me, I thought it was built into Python. Just asking me that question taught me something new and gave me an idea where to look.

Comment: The error you posted in your update does not match with your original code.

The error clearly states a syntax error, and not the error you previously mentioned.

Comment: The original errors are posted now.

Comment: It sounds like in the first case, either `TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX` or `GNU_PREFIX` is set and is `None`. `get` will not solve that issue.  Maybe print `substs` to figure out what's going on?

Comment: I can't fit the entire output of 'substs' here apparently, because it's about 60,000 characters. But I did give a sample above.

Comment: Neither GNU_PREFIX nor TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX appear in the output, but the definition of substs which I was asked to give earlier mentions something about pulling in an os.environ[var] if it's not defined in substs already (which is what the unmodified code does), and for some reason that trick stops working when I try to do it more than once in a single line.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution to this. It seems like the substrs.get command works in a very specific way that involves using keys and dictionaries, and everything you do with it has to be plugged in a certain way. It seems like it's extremely inflexible about how you invoke it for whatever reason.

This is the code that finally worked for me in this specific situation, it involved something called **os.getenv.** It is a bit weird-looking because I don't call both prefixes in the same way like I do in the Makefiles, but it effectively does what I want. I thought about changing TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX to match and use the same method, but I had weird issues with that as well. For some reason, this just works and it's good enough for my purposes.

```
proc = subprocess.Popen([substs.get('TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX','') + os.getenv('GNU_PREFIX') + 'readelf', '-d', lib], stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
```